# Rails form helper select when adding custom css class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This question comes up all the time, which probably points to a design flaw (@dhh)

WHy does this work:

```
<%= form.select :category_id, category_select_collection, {}, html_options =  { class: "form-select"} %>
```

but this does not work:

```
<%= form.select :category_id, category_select_collection, html_options =  { class: "form-select"} %>
```

I bet here's some subtlety about parameter ordering, named parameters, defaults and so on that I am tripping on. But I don't see where my understanding is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You have a parameter ordering problem. [`form.select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select) looks like this:

> `select(method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)`
>
> Wraps `ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper#select` for form builders:

The third argument are the options, the fourth are the HTML options so you want your `{ class: ... }` in the fourth argument.

You might also be misinterpreting what `html_options = { class: "form-select"}` means. That's an assignment to the local variable `html_options` inside the arguments to the `select` method. An assignment is an expression that evaluates to the RHS so it still works in the first case but you could say:

```
<%= form.select :category_id, category_select_collection, {}, any_local_variable_name = { class: "form-select"} %>
```

and achieve the same result (assuming of course that you're not using the `html_options` variable later on).